# Is there a way to keep the chunks always loaded in SSP vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any ways to keep a chunk (in any dimension) always loaded as long I am playing?

EDIT: I have possibly found a better way to do this : [BY SimplySarc](http://youtu.be/xIDHfxApRMQ)
EDIT2: I realised I have no idea what's happening the video so that might not be the answer.

Comment: When you say "of any dimension", do you mean of any size; or in any other Minecraft dimension, like the Nether?

Comment: I mean keeping any chunks always loaded whelther it is in the overworld, nether or the end.

Comment: If you have found an answer you should post it as an answer so that people can vote on it. Answers shouldn't be edited into the question.

Comment: whats actually happening is that the hoppers in the video he posted are actually creating something called 'residual chunks' which don't automatically unload the chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chunks are loaded outside of spawn only when a player is present. You can keep chunks loaded by having a second account logged in at or near the chunks you want to keep loaded.

Comment: hmm this makes me wonder if it cant be done by editing the mc properties. More research is needed.

Comment: Not without a mod. (yet)

Comment: Second account meaning opening up the lan or something? Sorry if this is obvious as I do not know too much about some of the newer updates.

Comment: @user1602020 Yes, like opening up the LAN to other players, except the "other players" are you running another instance of Minecraft and logged in with a second Minecraft account.

Comment: Well then, this will be the answer since I asked for any ways although this answer is not very favorable to me in my opinion.

Comment: This answer seems to imply that chunks inside spawn are always loaded and active. I believe this to be the case in SMP but can you clarify in your answer? Are there any such chunks in the nether?

Answer (score -5):

Minecarts keep their areas and rail network loaded (I'm not sure if it's chunks or just those spots, however). This was done in an update to fix automated carts flying out of the world.

That's the only vanilla thing I can think of that 'loads' areas.

Also, dimensions will always unload completely on vanilla, unless you use mods of course.

Comment: Do you have a reference?  I've never heard of this, and can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Never seen this, and have had minecarts stop on chunk edges until I went there again